# Outgoing transactions from this process must be FLAG_ONEWAY when using CompanionDeviceManager

Tags: android, android-companion-device

I am trying to use the CompanionDeviceManager as [described here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/companion-device-pairing) - but I am getting this error:

```
02-09 23:03:58.592  4729  4729 W Binder  : Outgoing transactions from this process must be FLAG_ONEWAY
02-09 23:03:58.592  4729  4729 W Binder  : java.lang.Throwable
02-09 23:03:58.592  4729  4729 W Binder  :  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:480)
02-09 23:03:58.592  4729  4729 W Binder  :  at android.companion.ICompanionDeviceDiscoveryService$Stub$Proxy.startDiscovery(ICompanionDeviceDiscoveryService.java:134)
02-09 23:03:58.592  4729  4729 W Binder  :  at com.android.server.companion.CompanionDeviceManagerService$2.onServiceConnected(CompanionDeviceManagerService.java:411)
02-09 23:03:58.592  4729  4729 W Binder  :  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1957)
02-09 23:03:58.592  4729  4729 W Binder  :  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1989)
02-09 23:03:58.592  4729  4729 W Binder  :  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
02-09 23:03:58.592  4729  4729 W Binder  :  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
02-09 23:03:58.592  4729  4729 W Binder  :  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
02-09 23:03:58.592  4729  4729 W Binder  :  at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:584)
02-09 23:03:58.592  4729  4729 W Binder  :  at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:380)
02-09 23:03:58.592  4729  4729 W Binder  :  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-09 23:03:58.592  4729  4729 W Binder  :  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
02-09 23:03:58.592  4729  4729 W Binder  :  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:919)
```

This happens on and Android one Device running Android 10 - anyone knows the reason for this and knows a workaround?

Comment: Please post an example of the code you are using, so others may reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please put, what have you done so far